# read from file with direct access c++

Tags: c++

Initial task: Create a program to add products and their characteristics. Features can be updated. The goods themselves can be deleted and display a list of all products.

I have a struct with 4 parameters. I need to store (write) a new record in a file and then be able to read this record by number id and do certain actions on the record. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


struct hardwareData {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    int quantity;
    float price;
};

int enterChoice(void);
void newRecord(fstream&);
void updateRecord(fstream&);
void outputRecord(fstream&);
void deleteRecord(fstream&);
void clearData(fstream&);
void outputLine(ostream&, hardwareData);

int main() {

    fstream inOutHardware("hardware.dat", ios::in | ios::out);

    if (!inOutHardware)
    {
        cerr << "Error." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

int current_choice;
inOutHardware.clear();
while (((current_choice = enterChoice()) != 0))
{

    switch (current_choice)
    {
    case 1:
        newRecord(inOutHardware);
        break;
    case 2:
        updateRecord(inOutHardware);
        break;
    case 3:
        deleteRecord(inOutHardware);
        break;
    case 4:
        outputRecord(inOutHardware);
        break;
    case 5:
        int num;
        cout << "Clear? (1 - так / 0 - нi)"         
        << endl << "Your choice - ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num == 1) {
            clearData(inOutHardware);
            cout << "succ!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "canceled" << endl;
        }

        break;
    default:
        cerr << "err" << endl;
        break;
    }

}

inOutHardware.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void newRecord(fstream &insertInFile)
{
    cout << "Input number (1-100): ";

    hardwareData hardware;

    int id;
    cin >> id;
    insertInFile.seekg((id - 1) + sizeof(hardware));

    insertInFile.read((char *)&hardware, sizeof(hardware));

    if (hardware.id == 0)
    {
        cout << "Input data" << endl;
        cin >> hardware.name >> hardware.quantity >> hardware.price;
        hardware.id = id;
        insertInFile.seekp((id - 1) * sizeof(hardwareData));
        insertInFile.write((char *)&hardware, sizeof(hardwareData));

    }
    else
        cerr << "№ " << id
        << " already have info" << endl;
}

void updateRecord(fstream &updateFile)
{
    int id;

    do
    {
        cout << "Input number for update: ";
        cin >> id;
    } while (id < 1 || id > 100);

    hardwareData hardware;
    updateFile.seekg((id - 1) * sizeof(hardware));

    updateFile.read((char *)&hardware, sizeof(hardware));

    if (hardware.id != 0)
    {
        outputLine(cout, hardware);
        cout << endl << "Input quan and price : ";

        int quan;
        float price;
        cin >> quan;
        cin >> price;
        hardware.quantity = quan;
        hardware.price = price;
        outputLine(cout, hardware);

        updateFile.seekp((id - 1) * sizeof(hardware));
        updateFile.write((char *)&hardware, sizeof(hardware));
    }
    else
        cerr << " № " << id
        << " empty " << endl;
}

void deleteRecord(fstream &deleteFromFile)
{
    cout << "Input number for delete (1-100): ";

    int id;
    cin >> id;
    deleteFromFile.seekg((id - 1) * sizeof(hardwareData));

    hardwareData hardware;
    deleteFromFile.read((char *)&hardware, sizeof(hardwareData));

    if (hardware.id != 0)
    {
        hardwareData blankhw = { 0, " ", 0,  0 };

        deleteFromFile.seekp((id - 1) * sizeof(hardware));
        deleteFromFile.write((char*)&blankhw, sizeof(hardware));
        cout << "№ " << id << " deleted" << endl;

    }
    else
        cout << "№ " << id << " empty" << endl;
}

void outputRecord(fstream &printRecord)
{

    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(6) << "ID"
        << setw(16) << "NAME" << setw(11) << "QUANTITY"
        << setiosflags(ios::right) << setw(10) << "PRICE" << endl;
    printRecord.seekg(0);

    hardwareData hardware;
    printRecord.read((char*)&hardware, sizeof(hardware));

    while (!printRecord.eof())
    {
        if (hardware.id != 0)
            outputLine(cout, hardware);

        printRecord.read((char*)&hardware, sizeof(hardware));
    }
}

void clearData(fstream &record) {
    hardwareData blankHardware = { 0, "", 0, 0.0 };

    record.seekp(0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        record.write((char *)&blankHardware, sizeof(blankHardware));
}


int enterChoice(void)

{
    cout << "Виберiть опцiю" << endl
    << " 1 - Add " << endl
    << " 2 - update" << endl
    << " 3 - delete" << endl
    << " 4 - output" << endl
    << " 5 - clear" << endl
    << " 0 - exit" << endl;

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}

void outputLine(ostream &output, hardwareData c)
{

    output << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(6) << c.id
    << setw(16) << c.name << setw(11) << c.quantity
    << setiosflags(ios::showpoint | ios::right)
    << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << c.price << endl;
}
```

Error: When i click on the output of all data from the file for the first time, everything works as a nominal and the next time, unknown characters are displayed infinity times.
[image: Infinity loop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a repeated problem of not checking if operations succeed, and then using uninitialized data because no initialization occurs.  For example:

```
hardwareData hardware;

int id;
cin >> id;
insertInFile.seekg((id - 1) + sizeof(hardware));

insertInFile.read((char *)&hardware, sizeof(hardware));

if (hardware.id == 0)
{
```

`hardwareData` has no constructor, so hardware is uninitialized and likely contains garbage.  It is NOT zero initialized unless you cause that to happen, such as:

```
hardwareData hardware{};
```

Next, `id` is uninitialized, again likely holding garbage.  If reading from cin fails, id remains holding a garbage value.  Initialize id to zero.

After that, if seekg fails by trying to seek to an invalid position in the file, you don't detect that.  Instead, you read from a stream that's in an error state, and that read will fail, and `hardware` is left holding garbage.  (When fixing this, don't check for EOF, check the failbit on the stream to detect error, or call good() on the stream to detect it's not in an error state.)

Then you check if `hardware.id` is zero as indication that the record isn't present, but if it holds garbage, you cannot reliably extract any meaning from any of its members.

I didn't look farther, so you may have other issues too, but these are important ones.